# Incrementing day in date every 6 cells starting at a cell that's not 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble incrementing my days correctly. I need them to increment every 6 cells (which is working) but it is starting the increment from cell 1, and i need it to start at cell 4.

here is my function

```
=DATE(YEAR($B$4),MONTH($B$4),DAY($B$4)+INT((ROW()/6)))
```

and here is an image of my spreadsheet

[image: spreadsheet]

Comment: you can offset your row() with -3 to account for moving from row 1 to row 4: *INT(((ROW()-3)/6))*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
=DATE(YEAR($B$4),MONTH($B$4),DAY($B$4)+INT((ROWS($1:1)/6)))
```

put **anywhere** and copy downward.